# Kotlin-moshi codegen inheritance with default values

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

If I have an open class and inherited data class from it, Kotlin-moshi codegen skip default value. Is this intended behaviour? How to make moshi-kotlin parse all values including default from superclass?

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class B(val bar: String) : A(foo = "foo")

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class A(val foo: String)

val b = B("bar")
```

`adapter.toJson(b)` prints `{"bar":"bar"}` without channel field.

Answer (score 2):

Make your superclass property mutable can solve your issue.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class B(val bar: String) : A(foo = "foo")

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class A(var foo: String)
```

Output

```
{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}
```